# Existe-t-il un « dictionnaire » de figures de style ?

Tags: vocabulaire, figure-de-style

En lisant le titre : « Walden ou la vie dans les bois », je me suis rappelé que ce titre ressemble à celui de Voltaire : « Candide ou l'optimisme ».
J'étais sûr qu'il y a une figure de style derrière ces titres et il s'avère que c'est une « antonomase ».

J'avais essayé de chercher sur internet comment trouver cette figure de style sans succès. J'ai donc dû demander à ma petite sœur en prépa pour avoir la réponse.

D'où ma question, existe-t-il un dictionnaire en ligne des figures de style ?

Comment: La plupart se trouvent probablement dans la Wikipédia : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_figures_de_style.

Comment: Le "Gradus, les procédés littéraires" de Dupriez (chez 10/18) est en ligne à https://archive.org/details/BernardDupriezGradusLesProcedesLitteraires/mode/2up
"Les figures de style" de Suhamy (Que Sais-je) est accessible à https://ia801003.us.archive.org/4/items/henrisuhamylesfiguresdestylequesaisje2013/Henri%20Suhamy%20-%20Les%20figures%20de%20style%20-%20Que%20sais-je%20%282013%29.pdf

Answer (score -2):

**Bien sûr, Of course!**

- Vous pourrez en trouver très facilement sur un moteur de recherche en faisant un requête de type "`Dictionnaire des figures de styles`".
- You can easily find one by searching "`Dictionnaire de figures de style`".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).